# How can a miner know how many blocks mined by him?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, altcoin-development, bitcoin-cli

I am working on an altcoin based on bitcoin-core, version 0.12.1 (this version including `setgenerate`).
Is their an option for a miner to know (using bitcoin-cli) how many blocks mined by him (after `setgenerate` was set to true), had been accepted by the network and had been inserted to the blockchain?

Comment: You wait for a sufficient number of new blocks to be mined on top of your block and see if the chain includes your block. For bitcoin, this is 6 blocks. If you see a chain with a different block at the height you submitted, your block was dropped.

Comment: OK, but is their a way to get the number of blocks which meets that definition by a command (or a set of commands) ? somethonk like `getblockcount`, but counted only for a specific miner.

Comment: No, you will have to maintain an index separately. Additionally, it may not always be possible to tell is multiple blocks were mined by the same miner

Comment: Can you elaborate about how to maintain this index? thanks

Comment: @RaghavSood For bitcoin, it's [100 blocks](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/consensus/consensus.h#L19), I believe.